AWS cdk gets stuck when deploying AWS:ECS:Service
I'm trying to deploy a frontend app. Whenever I try to deploy it gets stuck. It gets stuck when creating the ECS service. I searched online it says something is missing in the ecs service configuration. That there's a probe that queries the service. When I do
cdk deploy verbose

it says ecs cervice is not stable. What should I add so that my service gets table?
https://repost.aws/questions/QU_Ye-EnAiR2W6xdMEP6U7ew/ecs-service-creation-is-taking-too-much-time
I'm lost what is lost.
Here's my code:
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as ecs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as elbv2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';

export class WebAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create VPC
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'WebAppVpc', {
      maxAzs: 2 // Default is all AZs in the region
    });

    // Create ECS Cluster
    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'WebAppCluster', {
      vpc: vpc
    });

    // Add capacity to the ECS Cluster
    cluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroupCapacity', {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'),
      desiredCapacity: 2,
    });

    // Define Task Definition
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDef');

    // Add container to Task Definition
    const container = taskDefinition.addContainer('web', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('../../'),
      memoryLimitMiB: 512,
      cpu: 256,
    });

    container.addPortMappings({
      containerPort: 80,
      hostPort: 80,
      protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP,
    });

    // Create ECS Service
    const service = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'Service', {
      cluster,
      taskDefinition,
    });

    // Create Load Balancer
    const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener('Listener', {
      port: 80,
    });

    // Attach ECS Service to Load Balancer
    listener.addTargets('ECS', {
      port: 80,
      targets: [service],
    });

    // Output the Load Balancer DNS
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'LoadBalancerDNS', {
      value: lb.loadBalancerDnsName,
    });
  }
}



I found the problem. This app was exposeing port 3000. While ECS service needs to do a healthcheck at port 80. Port 80 always didn't respond because it was not exposed it didn't return a 200-ok. adding port forwarding from port 80 on the listener to port 3000 on the container solved the issue!
link of AWS question:
https://repost.aws/questions/QUFNacxdT3RfmaYAKP9KKDFA/stuck-deployment-issue-with-fargate-service-using-aws-cdk

It was only doing a health check on port 80 because that's what you configured all the port settings for in the CDK.  You have to configure the port settings to be whatever port your container is actually listening on. It will do a health check on whatever port you have configured. Also, it's the load balancer doing the health check, not the CDK, and it does it constantly, not just at deployment time. The CDK was just checking if the load balancer's first health check was succeeding or failing.
